# q-Generating function for plane partitions

Tags: combinatorics

If I include a variable $q_k$ in $\prod _k^n \frac{1}{\left(1-q_k x^k\right){}^k}$ and look at the coefficient of $x^n$, then I find that the polynomial in the $q_k$ can be read, term by term, as a partition of n : $q_1^2 q_3$ encodes the partition (311).
I would like to understand what the integer coefficients of the $q_i^a q_j^b$.. count.
Example for n=4, counting 13 plane partitions;
$4 q_4+3 q_3 q_1+3 q_2^2+2 q_2 q_1^2+q_1^4$ produces coefficients (in reverse lex order) [4,3,3,2,1]. If I try to relate these to the plane partitions, generated by row sum:

row sum 4: 5 pp : ((4)) , ((31)) , ((22)) , ((211)) , ((1111))
row sum 31 : 3 pp : ((3)(1))  ,  ((21)(1)) , ((111)(1))
row sum 22 : 2 pp : ((2)(2)) , ((11)(11))
row sum 211 : 2 pp : ((2)(1)(1)) , ((11)(1)(1))
row sum 1111 : 1 pp : ((1)(1)(1)(1))

By what property are the coefficients $q_i^a q_j^b$.. grouped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generating function  enumerates partitions where the contribution
of the elements of size $k$ must be composed of $k$ sequential blocks, 
possibly empty. The combinatorial species is composed of two sequence operators:
$$\prod_{k=1}^n \mathfrak{S}_{=k}(\mathfrak{S}(\mathcal{Q}_k \mathcal{Z}^k)).$$

Therefore   given   a   partition   $\mathbb{p}$   where   there   are
$a_j(\mathbb{p})$ elements of size $j$, $\mathbb{p}$ is counted with the factor
$$\prod_{j=1}^n [z^{a_j}] \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^j
= \prod_{j=1}^n {a_j+j-1\choose j-1}.$$

The following Maple code may interest you.

```
with(combinat);

dist :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local gf;

    gf := mul(1/(1-q[k]*x^k)^k, k=1..n);

    coeftayl(gf, x=0, n);
end;

ex :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local p, cf, el, gf, k;

    gf := 0;
    for p in partition(n) do
        cf := 1;
        for el in convert(p, multiset) do
            cf := cf * binomial(el[2]+el[1]-1, el[1]-1);
        od;

        gf := gf+cf*mul(q[p[k]], k=1..nops(p));
    od;

    gf;
end;
```

Consider this:

```
> seq(ex(n)-dist(n), n=1..9);
                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

The closed form that is implemented in the procedure **ex** makes it  possible to compute your generating function
easily  for large  values, whereas  this  is not feasible using the product form that you presented.

E.g. here is the distribution for $n=10:$
$$6\,{q_{{1}}}^{4}q_{{6}}+10\,{q_{{1}}}^{3}q_{{2}}q_{{5}}+{q_{{1}}}^{10}
+12\,{q_{{1}}}^{3}q_{{3}}q_{{4}}+12\,{q_{{1}}}^{2}{q_{{2}}}^{2}q_{{4}}
+3\,{q_{{1}}}^{7}q_{{3}}+12\,{q_{{1}}}^{2}q_{{2}}{q_{{3}}}^{2}\\+3\,{q_{
{1}}}^{6}{q_{{2}}}^{2}+12\,q_{{1}}{q_{{2}}}^{3}q_{{3}}+6\,{q_{{2}}}^{5
}+4\,{q_{{1}}}^{6}q_{{4}}+6\,{q_{{1}}}^{5}q_{{2}}q_{{3}}+4\,{q_{{1}}}^
{4}{q_{{2}}}^{3}+5\,{q_{{1}}}^{5}q_{{5}}\\+8\,{q_{{1}}}^{4}q_{{2}}q_{{4}
}+6\,{q_{{1}}}^{4}{q_{{3}}}^{2}+9\,{q_{{1}}}^{3}{q_{{2}}}^{2}q_{{3}}+5
\,{q_{{1}}}^{2}{q_{{2}}}^{4}+2\,{q_{{1}}}^{8}q_{{2}}+10\,q_{{1}}{q_{{3
}}}^{3}\\+18\,{q_{{2}}}^{2}{q_{{3}}}^{2}+16\,{q_{{2}}}^{3}q_{{4}}+24\,q_
{{1}}q_{{2}}q_{{3}}q_{{4}}+10\,{q_{{1}}}^{2}{q_{{4}}}^{2}+15\,q_{{1}}{
q_{{2}}}^{2}q_{{5}}+15\,{q_{{1}}}^{2}q_{{3}}q_{{5}}\\+12\,{q_{{1}}}^{2}q
_{{2}}q_{{6}}+7\,{q_{{1}}}^{3}q_{{7}}+15\,{q_{{5}}}^{2}+24\,q_{{4}}q_{
{6}}+21\,q_{{3}}q_{{7}}+16\,q_{{2}}q_{{8}}+9\,q_{{1}}q_{{9}}\\+24\,{q_{{
3}}}^{2}q_{{4}}+20\,q_{{2}}{q_{{4}}}^{2}+30\,q_{{2}}q_{{3}}q_{{5}}+20
\,q_{{1}}q_{{4}}q_{{5}}+18\,{q_{{2}}}^{2}q_{{6}}+18\,q_{{1}}q_{{3}}q_{
{6}}\\+14\,q_{{1}}q_{{2}}q_{{7}}+8\,{q_{{1}}}^{2}q_{{8}}+10\,q_{{10}}.$$

Comment: I interpret your answer as saying "the coefficients of $q_i^a q_j^b$ can calculated from the i,j,.. and a,b,.. but there is no such thing as a one-on-one link between a given plane partition and the $q_i^a q_j^b$ it 'belongs' to.". Do I understand you correctly? For reference, a small Mathematica implementation of your program: content[par_List]:=Table[Count[par,k],{k,Max[par]}]; riedel[par_List]:=Times @@ MapIndexed[ Binomial[#1+Tr[#2]-1, Tr[#2]-1]&,content[par]]; riedel/@IntegerPartitions[4]

Comment: Silly me! Take any plane partition and get the 'content' vector ( a 1's, b 2's, etc ), sort and reverse, and you get again a 'linear' partition. And it's *those* partitions the q-generation function counts. Staring me in the face!